What are the benefits of Saraswati Sahasranama according to Hindu scriptures?
What are the specific benefits and the good qualities that are bestowed upon when one regularly chants the Sahasranama of goddess Saraswati? Please provide the source of reference . Thank you.

The benefits are as follows:

Translation:

The above are the thousand  sacred names of Maha Saraswati Devi. These
Names are filled with mantras which are of confidential meaning
constituting the quintessence of invaluable knowledge, wisdom  and
discernment that Maha Saraswati is all about. (1)
Those who accomplish full reading and hearing of the Devi's names
three times a day are indeed bestowed the best of everything.They are
blessed high with complete fulfilment of achieving unique Vidyas most
certainly(2).
He will gain wealth and prosperity in full along with sons and grand
sons. Even the dumb, mute and wreched human beings  once exposed to
the Sahasra naama of Saraswati would be eligible to excellence in the
domains of Knowledge by the grace of Chaturmukha (3).
All those absorbed in this Sahasranamaa shall indeed get closer to
Devi. This Sahasranama is a concentrate of Sarva Mantras and  is the
conferrer of Sarva Vidyas (4).
This Highly Confidential Sahasra naama of Devi Vani naama is the most
apropriate and rewarding to persons of my minimal standing and average
intellect in all respects.(6).

Note: Partial only, fifth verse and part of sixth verse is not fully translated.
